# Showing Summary of variables/Methods in java

Tags: java, eclipse

In eclipse when we press ctrl+tab it shows a intellisense.And in intellisence when we locate a variable or method then a related summary will displayed.
In visual studio you can create this by just typing this /// (three backslashes) above method.
My question is how can i do this in eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These descriptions are generated from Javadoc annotations.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html

Answer (score 4):

Start typing what's thought of as a JavaDoc comment, "/**", and hit Return.  It can also generate the comment block for you from the Outline's context menu for that member.